# The flow of a GRANDPA round

Tags: grandpa

I am curious about some details regarding a **GRANDPA** round ([explained in detail](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/are-justification-in-the-block-the-actual-votes-cast-by-validators-in-grandpa/5980#5980)).

1. An elected validator that is designated as the **primary** broadcasts the highest block that it thinks could be final from the previous round ([ref](https://medium.com/polkadot-network/polkadot-consensus-part-2-grandpa-fb1963ef6c70)).

- Question 1: How is this primary chosen?

2. The elected validators gossip a **pre-vote** for the highest block that it thinks should be finalised.
3. Each elected validator computes the highest block that can be finalised based on the set of pre-votes. If the set of pre-votes extends the last finalised
   chain, then each elected validator will gossip a **pre-commit** to that chain.

- Question 2: in order to make a pre-commit, does a validator need the pre-votes of all the elected validators?

4. Each elected validator waits to receive the pre-commits to form and gossip a **commit message** on the newly finalised chain.

- Question 3: in order to make a commit, does a validator need the pre-commits of all the elected validators (**ev**) or is (2/3**ev** + 1) enough?

5. Now all the elected validators have the commit message, the BABE selected author includes it in the new block as part of the **justification**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Once a certain threshold of pre-votes has been received, a primary block is selected. This is the block that will be finalized in the current round. The primary block is the block with the most pre-votes, and it must also have at least two-thirds of the total nominators behind it.
2. No, a validator does not need to have the pre-votes of all the elected validators in order to make a pre-commit. Once a certain threshold of pre-votes has been reached, a primary block is selected for finalization in the current round. The nominated validators then send pre-commits for the selected block.
3. No, a validator does not need the pre-commits of all the elected validators in order to make a commit