# Is there any way to get the validators signatures of the finalized blocks in substrate based chains?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, substrate-node-template

I need the signatures of the validators who have signed on the produced and finalized blocks.
For example, In cosmos-SDK based blockchains blocks contains the signatures(and validators addresses) of the validators who have voted on that block.
Is there some way to get this data from existing RPCs.

Answer (score 1):

As for Polkadot these signatures are included in the justification, have a look at [this detailed explanation](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/are-justification-in-the-block-the-actual-votes-cast-by-validators-in-grandpa). You can query this information with the [RPC call](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2F1rpc.io%2Fdot#/rpc) -> `grandpa` -> `proveFinality(blockNumber)`.